# Как передать результат в другой компонент?

Tags: reactjs

сломал всю голову, не могу передать результат выполнения функции ***onShowCard*** в  для дальнейшего отображения данных, подскажите пожалуйста, как быть?

https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-fog-b3xcz

Пытаюсь по клику вытащить id карты из списка карт, далее передать владельца карты в  для того чтобы отобразить его на карте в поле ***CardHolder***

Comment: объясните пошагово, что ожидается от выполнения: нажимаю сюда, ведет туда и выход должен такой. Во всем коде просто никто не будет сидеть разбираться.

Comment: Почему-то сайт решил убрать половину названий функций, что я добавил...
Я пытаюсь по клику на элементе в card-list.js узнать id этого элемента, затем передать его в <AppCard/> для того, чтобы там отобразить данные, которые ранее получил по id в card-list.js с помощью onClick. 
Вкратце, я пытаюсь отобразить все данные той, или иной кредитной карты, на карте, что нарисована в шапке (AppCard)

Comment: При обмене данными между компонентами, нежелательно создавать зависимость логики от элементов (по id, либо другому свойству/признаку) - есть более разумные варианты... redux, например.